# Calculate kernel space of matrix map and its orthonormal space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

The question asks:

a) What is kernel space of linear map defined by  $$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 6 \\
3 & 6 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

b) Give orthonormal basis for map's kernel from a)

My attempt of a)

[image]

I attempted to find the kernel space, but I am not sure if I am right, furthermore, I don't know how to approach b). Thank you for any help

Comment: It's fine. For b) find the dimension of the orthogonal space and actually (the transpose of) any row of the original matrix is perpendicular to the kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Put another way, the kernel of the transformation has $\bigl\{[-2,1,0]^\dagger,[-3,0,1]^\dagger\bigr\}$ as a basis. Use Gram-Schmidt method to determine an orthonormal basis for the kernel.

Comment: Would this be correct then? https://imgur.com/a/mRsf0BB

Comment: I did forget to normalize the u2 vector, so I would need to multiply it by 5/sqrt(70) but other than that it should be fine

Comment: @Sam333 Looks good!

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

So since ${\rm ker}M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-2y-3z\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: y,z\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ hence a basis for ${\rm ker}M$ is given by $\beta=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Define $v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

An orthonormal basis for ${\rm ker}M$ is given by $\beta^{*}=\{u_1,u_2\}$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ is  obtained by Gram-Schmidt algorithm:

- $\displaystyle u_1 =\frac{v_1}{||v_1||}$.
- $\displaystyle u_2=\frac{v_{2}-\langle v_{2},u_{1}\rangle u_{1}}{||v_{2}-\langle v_{2},u_{1}\rangle u_{1}||}$.

Where $||\cdot||$ the norm induced by the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. If you haven't seen general inner products, then you may be working with the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is just the dot product between vectors.

Using the dot product as the inner product we get $$\beta^{*}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{35}}{35}\\ \frac{\sqrt{35}}{7}\\-\frac{3\sqrt{35}}{35} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}\\0\\  \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$

Recall the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given by $$\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix} \right\rangle=ax+by+cz$$ and the norm induced by the dot product is given by $$\left|\left|\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\right|\right|=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^2 + c^2 }.$$

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, so I attemted normalizing v1 and v2 and (with the help of symbolab) I got this: https://imgur.com/a/rqHplsc Any idea why those are different vectors, or are they the same as your answer?

Comment: You're looking an orthonormal basis $\beta^{*}=\{u_1,u_2\}$, so it's not sufficient normalize $v_1$ and $v_2$. You need use the formula what I wrote in my post about $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks again, I meant I didnt just normalize them, I used this feature and thats what I got using [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/gram-schmidt-calculator) But then I tried to do it by myself by looking at Khan Academy Gram Schmidt process example video and got [this](https://imgur.com/a/mRsf0BB)

Comment: Any idea where I could have made a mistake? Cuz Im pretty sure I got it right