# Let $T:\mathbb{P_2\to R}$ be transformation. Find basis for kernel of $T$ that is orthogonal w. r. t. inner product. $⟨f(x),g(x)⟩=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

**Problem**

> - Let $T : \mathbb{P_2\to R}$ be the function defined by $T(p(x))= p(1)$. Verify that $T$ is in fact a linear transformation. (There are two things you need to verify for this.)
> - Let $T$ be the transformation defined above. Find a basis for the kernel of $T$ that is orthogonal with respect to the inner product.$$
>   \langle f(x),g(x)\rangle =\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm{dx}$$
>   (That is, find a basis for the kernel of $T$ such that all pairs of distinct basis vectors are orthogonal with respect to this inner product.)

**What is the question asking in the second part?** How to find a basis for the kernel of $T$ that is orthogonal with respect to an inner product?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1) Don't post images, use mathjax instead to write formulas. There's mathjax tutorial on this site. 2) Do you know about the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: I would seem like the image explains what is being asked. Please explain what you don't understand of that explanation.

Comment: This answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4434547/1027216 should be useful. You should read it and then you can show your work here.

Comment: The kernel of $T$ contains all $p\in\mathbb P_2$ with $T(p)=p(1) =0$. I guess $\mathbb P_2$ means "space of polynomials with degree less or equal to two"? Then $\dim\mathbb P_2=3$ and $\dim \text{im} T=\dim \mathbb R=1$. Hence $\dim \text{ker} T=2$. Find an one-degree polynomial with $p(1) =0$.